# Error while creating project with eclipse

Tags: eclipse

[image]

[image]

I am having problem with eclipse while creating project. I am doing this in my office. I am not able to find problem where it from occur. kindly help me

Comment: No that question is about hot to plug in Force.comIDE in eclipes

Comment: weird approach but works for me some times, make sure internet is working and eclipse is not firewall restrict. After that press retry 5-20 times even you see the error message it will eventually connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be due to proxy settings in your office. In eclipse go to Window >> Preferences >> General >> network settings and set your proxies as per your office proxy settings ( refer internet explorer to know what proxy they use)

Comment: do you mean about proxy.host =********
proxy.port = **
proxy.user = *******
proxy.pwd = *******?